# Problems Writing Output to File

Tags: file, unix, while-loop, ifs

I am reading in a small csv file in the format `size,name` - one set per line.  For my testing file I have two lines in the csv file.

If I use the code

```
while
        IFS=',' read -r size name
do
        printf "%s\n" "name"
done < temp1.txt
```

The `name` values for each of the lines is printed to the terminal.

If I use the code

```
while
        IFS=',' read -r size name
do
        printf "%s\n" "name" > temp2.txt
done < temp1.txt
```

Then only the last `name` is printed to the `temp2.txt` file.

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `>`, so that the file gets truncated every time. Instead, use `>>` to append:

So it should be like this:

```
        printf "%s\n" "name" >> temp2.txt
                             ^^
```

All together:

```
while
        IFS=',' read -r size name
do
        printf "%s\n" "name" >> temp2.txt
done < temp1.txt
```

---

Basic example:

```
$ echo "hello" > a
$ echo "bye" > a
$ cat a
bye                        # just last line gets written

$ echo "hello" >> a
$ echo "bye" >> a
$ cat a
hello
bye                        # everything gets written
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel stupid for that.  It wasn't quite as simple though, so I had to add in `rm` commands to clear the directory up as it works.

Comment: Good to read that! Don't blame you for the error, it is quite common and happens to the best of us :)